# Draw a binary tree using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

I'm trying to draw a binary tree using `tikz` package.

If I use only `circle`, I get a tree. But I want to represent a `subtree` using a `triangle`. Now the tree gets uneven. I want to attach the arrows to the top of the `triangle` and also want the size of the `triangle` comparable to the size of the `circle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,matrix,positioning}
\tikzset
{
    treenode/.style = {circle, draw=black, align=center, minimum size=1cm},
    subtree/.style  = {isosceles triangle, draw=black, align=center, minimum height=0.5cm, minimum width=1cm, shape border rotate=90, anchor=north}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering

\caption{An illustration of a simple delete operation. \label{fig:simple}}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,
    level distance = 1.5cm},scale=0.6, transform shape]
    \node [treenode] {$X$ \\ 100}
    child
    {
        node [treenode] {$Y$ \\ 50} 
        child
        {
            node [treenode] {$Z$ \\ 40} 
            child
            {
                node [treenode] {$S1$ \\ 30} 
            }
            child
            {
                node [treenode] {$S2$ \\ 60} 
            }
        }
        child
        {
            node [subtree] {$Z$ \\ 200} 
        }
    }
    child
    {
        node [subtree] {$Z$ \\ 200} 
    }
;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: thank you! I'm trying to learn TeX to get a paper written

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. With the OP's current setting the circles and triangles are of comparable size as long as the text is not written into the `subtree` nodes. So a possible solution is to write the text later after the drawing is done.  This is shown by the last 2 lines of codes.
2. To have the arrows pointing to the tip of a triangle, the following line is added to the corresponding parent nodes

   edge from parent path ={(\tikzparentnode.-50) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)} % -50 is adjustable.
3. If the triangles are still incomparable, one can write `scale=0.9` into the `subtree` style for shrinking adjustment.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper size={10cm,8cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,matrix,positioning}
\tikzset
{
    treenode/.style = {circle, draw=black, align=center, minimum size=1cm},
    subtree/.style  = {isosceles triangle, draw=black, align=center, minimum height=0.5cm, minimum width=1cm, shape border rotate=90, anchor=north}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering

\caption{An illustration of a simple delete operation. \label{fig:simple}}
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1, level distance = 1.5cm}, scale=0.6,transform shape]
    \node [treenode] {$X$ \\ 100}
    child
    {
        node [treenode] {$Y$ \\ 50} 
        child
        {
            node [treenode] {$Z$ \\ 40} 
            child
            {
                node [treenode] {$S1$ \\ 30} 
            }
            child
            {
                node [treenode] {$S2$ \\ 60} 
            }
        }
        child[edge from parent path ={(\tikzparentnode.-50) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}]
        {
            node [subtree,yshift=0.4cm] (a) {}   % delay the text till later
        }
    }
    child[edge from parent path ={(\tikzparentnode.-30) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}]
    {
        node [subtree,yshift=0.4cm] (b) {}       % delay the text till later
    }
;
% ------------------------------------------------ put the text into subtree nodes
\node[align=center,yshift=0.1cm] at (a) {$Z$\\200};
\node[align=center,yshift=0.1cm] at (b) {$Z$\\200};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you need to understand for `TiKZ` nodes is that `minimum size` means exactly this `minimum`, i.e., if `node contents` needs a larger size, `TiKZ` will take it.

Here you have an example with your `treenode` and `subtree` (I've replaced `isosceles triangle` by an equilater one with `regular polygon`). As you can see, if node contents is empty, `minimum size` is respected and there is a relation between circle and triangle size. But as soon as nodes contain some text, their sizes are adapted acordingly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,matrix,positioning}
\tikzset
{
    treenode/.style = {circle, draw=black, align=center, minimum size=1cm, anchor=center},
    subtree/.style  = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, draw=black, align=center, minimum size=1cm, anchor=center}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[treenode,blue] at (0,0) {};
\node[subtree,red] at (0,0) {};

\node[treenode] at (2,0) {$Y$ \\ 50};
\node[treenode, blue] at (2,0) {};

\node[subtree, inner sep=0pt] at (4,0) {$Y$ \\ 50};
\node[subtree, red, inner sep=0pt] at (4,0) {};
\node[treenode, blue] at (4,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You will have to play with minimum sizes for circular and triangular nodes if you want they present a similar size.

A second problem with your code was `anchor=north` option in `subtree` node definition while `treenodes` had a default `anchor=center`. Then, top most vertex of subtree was aligned with center point of corresponding treenode.

Your last question was about arrow to north vertex. Use [child anchor=north].

The result could be:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,matrix,positioning}
\tikzset
{
    treenode/.style = {circle, draw=black, align=center, 
                          minimum size=1cm, anchor=center},
    subtree/.style  = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, 
                          draw=black, align=center, 
                          minimum size=1cm, anchor=center}
}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,
    level distance = 1.5cm},scale=0.6, transform shape]
    \node [treenode] {$X$ \\ 100}
    child
    {
        node [treenode] {$Y$ \\ 50} 
        child
        {
            node [treenode] {$Z$ \\ 40} 
            child
            {
                node [treenode] {$S1$ \\ 30} 
            }
            child
            {
                node [treenode] {$S2$ \\ 60} 
            }
        }
        child [child anchor=north]
        {
            node [subtree] {$Z$ \\ 200} 
        }
    }
    child [child anchor=north]
    {
        node [subtree] {$Z$ \\ 200} 
    }
;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

To attach the arrows to the top of the subtrees then say`child[child anchor=apex]`