# Undefined control sequence. \usetikzlibrary for creating a tree

Tags: tikz-trees, trees

I'm trying to create a binary tree using TeXstudio. I used the instructions listed in this question:
[Drawing binary trees with LaTeX labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203399/drawing-binary-trees-with-latex-labels)

When I compile it, I got this error:

[image]

I checked if I have the package or not and here is the packages I have:

[image: Packages]

this is the result I got after adding \usepackage{tikz}:
[image]

Comment: You don't have `\usepackage{tikz}` declared in your preamble. It's not enough to have it in MiKTeX, you have to load it in your document. Read also [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 11):

The implicit load of TikZ package in that example comes from the fact that `standalone` class has an option to load TikZ automatically if you use

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
```

but if you are using `article` class then you have to explicitly load the packages hence you need to add

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

to your preamble before `\usetikzlibrary{}`

Comment: I tried it and this is what I got  https://www.4shared.com/photo/JKWsGKAuce

Comment: @F505 You need to compile with LuaTeX